# Installing Vagrant on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: vagrant

I'd like to install Vagrant software on Ubuntu 16.04, but their [download page](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html), only lists Debian and Cent OS. Is it possible to run this software on Ubuntu?

Comment: Debian package (.deb) should actually work on ubuntu too

Comment: You can install it with `sudo apt-get install vagrant`